# Is there any Programming language that can directly execute MathType Formula?

Tags: java, ide, programming-languages, rich-text-editor, mathtype

Let's take an example of Java. A rich text IDE is never found for now, and plain-text IDE is the mainstream.

I have read many times Latex formula in IDE with codes from github and it's hard to understand the symbols without the help of any TeX-like software.

I just envision the birth of such an IDE which can integrate Word, OneNote, etc., where codes like class can be highlighted, copy paste like picture while editted like plain/rich html, multimedia objects can be used as explanations, just like the matlab helper not the plain javadoc, can be compared with 2 or more classes in multi-column in one file in one time, which is a great view of Java Class hierarchy, just like what OneNote can do, so that I can get rid of the limit that codes can only be written in one column in plain text editor. Frankly, OneNote is not an IDE but is a real rich text IDE prototype, which contains all the intuitiveness of writing/ordering something such as codes but to run codes, However, these features are just like a patent which can only be seen in OneNote, and can not be found in any famous or less programming environment. I can not help recalling, historically, the development of the width of rail tracks limits the size of imagination, which repeats in my brain each time I use OneNote.

What's more, although many IDE contains highlight grammar, it is still a plain-text code, which can be generated very fast from rich text one by just removing explanation areas.

The Mathtype-like formula is so much better than plan-text formula in plain text IDE, which I can feel in OneNote by pasting codes and formula together, especially when it is a fraction or rooting formula. What a pity, the formula can not run directly. Actually, they can be generated from the same format, namely xml-like rich text.

I just found one interesting piece of such a code in a PDF file from the Unicode website, which is  much better to capture the real function of the program function:

```js
void IHBMWM(void)
{
 gammap = gamma*sqrt(1 + I2);
 upsilon = cmplx(gamma+gamma1, Delta);
 alphainc = alpha0*(1-(gamma*gamma*I2/gammap)/(gammap + upsilon));
 if (!gamma1 && fabs(Delta*T1) < 0.01)
  alphacoh = -half*alpha0*I2*pow(gamma/gammap, 3);
 else
 {
  Gamma = 1/T1 + gamma1;
  I2sF = (I2/T1)/cmplx(Gamma, Delta);
  betap2 = upsilon*(upsilon + gamma*I2sF);
  beta = sqrt(betap2);
  alphacoh = 0.5*gamma*alpha0*(I2sF*(gamma + upsilon)/(gammap*gammap –  betap2))*((1+gamma/beta)*(beta –  upsilon)/(beta + upsilon)- (1+gamma/gammap)*(gammap –  upsilon)/(gammap + upsilon));
 }
 alpha1 = alphainc + alphacoh;
}
```

```js
void IHBMWM(void)
{
  =  •   (1 +  2);
  =  +  1 +  • Δ ;
  _inc =  0 • (1 − ( •  •  2/ ’ )/( ’ +  ));

 if (!  1|| fabs(Δ •  1) < 0.01)
   _coh = − .5 •  0 •  2 • pow( / ’ , 3);
 else
 {
   = 1/ 1+  1;
   2ℱ = ( 2/ 1)/(Γ +  • Δ );
   2=  • ( +  •  2ℱ );
   =    2;
   coh= .5 •  •  0 • ( 2ℱ ( +  )/( ’ •  ’ −  2))× ((1 +  / ) • ( −  )/( +  ) − (1 +  / ’ ) • ( ’ −  )/( ’ +  ));
 }

  1=  inc+  coh;
}
```

[image: For the layout reason, the final version is in image.]

The length of the two above is obviously longer than the 3rd one.

If you can not see the 3rd in image, please visit the [Original Pdf here](http://www.unicode.org/notes/tn28/UTN28-PlainTextMath-v2.pdf), from page 33 to 35.

***A small question is***, should such a habit of plain text programming still be thought as a good one after such an IDE come into being? High level programming language is stuck with this prejudice of being satisfied with plain text coding while the helper is multimedia.The varients/constants are all ASCII-like, while Unicode sets are just partially supported. And it is so elegent in Mathtype-like formula to read and use in brain, while it is impossible to subscript an index like what we read in textbook in an IDE and programming languages like Java still need brackets.

***The final question is*** whether such an IDE or Programming language that can run Mathtype-like formula or code like Math exist or not?

***PS***: I know the executing order in the Mathtype formula can result in low effciency when loops exist, but, it is not the problem, as a programmer, I can manually seperate these polynomials into fragments and add them in loops, but machine can facilitate them, too.

***PS2***: Mathematica is great for Math researchers around science community, despites its high price. I try to download and use it and I am really attracted by its simplicity-like interface and notation system, such as many games can be implemented with much fewer lines and the helper is very human-friendly and intelligent, just like an input method! And the helper is also able to run codes, which is a definate improvement for this and following generation to learn programming, maybe not only the Mathematica language.

Firstly, the concept "Notebook" in Mathematica is the ultimate code editor that I can find for now, which can use Mathtype-like components in representng algorithms and it is just so valuable to adopt such a concept into other Programming languages or their plain-text IDEs, because Mathematica has its own limits such as the lack of certain existent features in other language which are also important.

I can not help recalling the traditional way of command line programming in windows or linux in last century, which is not so much different from plain-text IDE programming nowadays. By the way, the Mathematica workbench is a specified version of Eclipse IDE which is just not able to code in a Mathematica "Notebook" way, what a pity for now.

Reading others' codes is much more difficult than writing codes, especially of algorithms, and the codes I write are difficult to read in future both for me and others, if there is not a way to just display Mathtype-like symbols in rich text IDE like what Mathematica can do, running Symbols is another thing.

Secondly, even in "Notebook", the components can not be arranged freely in an OneNote way, the width is infinity means a real infinity in OneNote, you can paste anything into the right side far from the first column filled with anything like rich text in OneNote and can be viewed using horizontal scroll bar. The obvious benefit of this feature is an umlimited comparing 2 or more codes from the same parent class or algorithm variants, I guess its also useful for version controlling, just like a continious scrolling of horizontally comparing 10 files in BeyondCompare without the vertical scroll bars of each but the last one, just like a 1*N matrix of classes, not one column.

Maybe several years later, those features as I mensioned can be realized in Mathematica, too.

I heard about "Source code is the documentation" like old sayings, which is not yet the reality at all.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe not MathType exactly, but [Mathematica](http://www.wolfram.com/mathematica/) with its IDE allows you to perform symbolic programming with all those fancy mathematical symbols. Its "successor", [Wolfram Language](http://www.wolfram.com/language/), should be able to do it as well and more.

The only problem is that its quite expensive. But there is a 30-day trial version so you might check if this suits your needs.

Comment: Hi, maddening! Thank you very much for the Mathematica advice and after trying to use it, I think this philosophy of representing and running Mathtype-like symbols as codes will survive among other Programming languages, both functional and OO ones. I happen to find Mathics, which is similar to Mathematica and is build on Sympy in Python, which is for free and an open source project. Although I find Python is not friendly to Non-Latin Character in both Windows and Linux, I still think this imitaion of symbolic integration is important and efficient.

Comment: Glad to hear that it helped you. I played around with Mathics but at the time it was still on not-production-ready state and I didn't stick to it - however it's very promising and I believe many people will find it useful already. Thanks for reminding me about it!